# Unable to get callback of addEventListener on div tag with role = button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the div element with role 'button'

```
<div id="BTB-btn" class="home" ng-click="goBTB()" title="Back to Bookshelf" ng-class="{'spiral-bookshelf' : CONFIG.subDomain== 'spiralenglish'}" ng-style="toggleBTB()" tabindex="10" role="button" aria-label="Back to Bookshelf" ng-hide="CONFIG.subDomain== 'oup'"></div>
```

When I try to add an event listener to it, I do not get a callback

```
var button = document.getElementById('BTB-btn');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var messageToPost = {"ButtonId":"BTB-btn"};
  webkit.messageHandlers.backButtonClicked.postMessage(messageToPost);
```

Note - I am getting the same callback with other normal div and button tag

Comment: What do you mean by 'callback' here - what exactly is not working as you expect? The `postMessage()`? Please edit the question to give a clearer description of the issue and share any debugging attempts you've made.

Comment: You also appear to be using Angular yet are adding a native event handler. Also note that I removed the 'swift' tag as that's a language used to create apps primarily on Apple devices, and has nothing to do with JS or the web in general